# Search zipped *and* non-zipped files in one hit

Tags: linux, grep, zip, gzip

I have a folder with a mix of zipped and unzipped log files which i want to search.

I can search the non-zipped with

```
grep -r "my-search-string" /path/to/folder
```

and search the zipped files with

```
find /path/to/folder -name "*.gz" -exec zcat "{}" + | grep "my-search-string"
```

Is there a one-liner i can use to search all the zipped and unzipped files in `/path/to/folder` ?

thanks, Max

Answer (score 5, accepted):

zgrep is your friend!

> ```
>    Zgrep  invokes grep on compressed or gzipped files.  All options speci‐
>    fied are passed directly to grep.  If no file is  specified,  then  the
>    standard input is decompressed if necessary and fed to grep.  Otherwise
>    the given files are uncompressed if necessary and fed to grep.
> ```

I just noticed that some zgrep versions don't have a -r option. In that case you can use your find pattern to catch all files and use zgrep instead of grep, such as:

> find . -type f -exec zgrep 'my search string' "{}" \;

Answer (score 1):

Export a few useful variables for 'my-search-string' and path, then search:

```
SEARCH='my-search-string' ; SEARCHPATH='/path/to/folder' ; grep -r "$SEARCH" $SEARCHPATH && find $SEARCHPATH -name "*.gz" -exec zcat "{}" + | grep "$SEARCH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use zgrep with grep

```
 zgrep -e  'inital text to search' ../../usr/local/*.* | grep 'more filter in zgrep respond'
```